# Angular/SignalR Error: Failed to start the connection. SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, signalr

Try to make simple angular/signalR application.

My Hub class:

```
namespace Gameserver.Hubs
{
    public class SignalRHub : Hub
    {
        public Task Send()
        {
            return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", "Message from the server");
        }
    }
}
```

my startup.cs:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

and a component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnection } from '@aspnet/signalr-client';

export class CoreComponent implements OnInit 
{
  private connection: HubConnection;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.connection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:49756/signalr/');

    this.connection.on('send', data =>{
      console.log(data);
    })

    this.connection.start()
      .then(() => console.log('connected'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection: ' + err));
  }
```

After running got this error from `Loggers.js`:

```
Error: Failed to start the connection. SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: When you access "localhost:49756/signalr/" directly by your browser, is any authentication required?

Comment: No, it's not required

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, and yes, authentication is required for my hub, any solution?

Comment: Try to look my answer: that solution contains authentication data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying another two packages I found one which works fine.
https://github.com/HNeukermans/ng2-signalR
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-signalr

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, to use a connection without credentials in SignalR, when you start the connection you must indicate that no credentials will be used, for this you must set the "withCredentials" option to "false"

```
this.connection.start({withCredentials: false})
.then(() => console.log('connected'))
.catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection: ' + err));
```